# How to get the values from object?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

[image]
I figured out how to make it in key value pair. But I tried getting values through different but none of them works.
This is how my map looks like. I am unable to get the values based on key.

Here is the code I am using

```js
var storevalue = new Array();
storevalue = new Map(Object.entries(JSON.parse('{!filterModelstr}')));
```

Image shows what `storevalue` looks like.

```js
cols.forEach(function(col) {

  var filterInstance = gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance(col.getId());
  // Set the model for the filter

  filterInstance.setModel({
    condition1: {
      type: storevalue.get(col.getId()).storeTypeOperator,//Giving error at ths point 
      filter: storevalue.get(col.getId()).storefiltervalue,
    },
    operator: 'AND',
    condition2: {
      type: storevalue.get(col.getId()).storeTypeOperator,
      filter: storevalue.get(col.getId()).storefiltervalue,
    },
  });
});
```

I am planning to assign values to type and filter which is not happening. How can I solve this scenario.

Comment: Please don't use a screenshot and copy past your code directly in the question

Comment: @MickaelB.Okay. Please let me know what am i doing wrong

Comment: What is `JSON.parse('{!filterModelstr}')`? That's not even JSON.

Comment: I am serializing to JSON in controller. Later I am parsing in JS.

Comment: @Karan Yes it returns like that. But i am not getting the value. what am i doing wrong

Comment: Then it should be working. Once verify that if your `storevalue` is populated `asynchronously` then make sure that `cols.forEach` code executes after `storevalue` is populated.

Comment: @Karan Yup. I am populating before foreach.I am getting the size as well using map.size

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think what you are doing is pretty correct and should work provided your `storevalue.get(col.getId())` method works and returns value object.

try to debug to see if your `storevalue.get` is giving correct json or not.

check out this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XDl6CtSmpokWzgfW) i made to replicate what you are trying to do.